# what is wrong with this htaccess multi level directory rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multi-level

I have some problems with my htaccess...

I want to have my url's like this:

```
http://example.com/artist/
http://example.com/artist/rihanna/
http://example.com/artist/rihanna/biography/
http://example.com/artist/rihanna/video/
http://example.com/artist/rihanna/news/
```

The problem is all of the url's work except for "http://example.com/artist/"

```
RewriteRule ^artist/([^_]*)/biography/$ /artist-biography.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^artist/([^_]*)/biography?$ /artist/$1/biography/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^artist/([^_]*)/video/$ /artist-video.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^artist/([^_]*)/video?$ /artist/$1/video/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^artist/([^_]*)/news/$ /artist-news.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^artist/([^_]*)/news?$ /artist/$1/news/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^artist/([^_]*)/$ /artist.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^artist/([^_/]+)$ /artist/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^artist/$ /artist-page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^artist?$ /artist/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What happens when you try to access `http://example.com/artist/`?

Comment: with or without a backslash i get an error : "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

> RewriteRule ^artist/([^_]*)?$ /artist/$1/ [R=301,L]

will match `http://example.com/artist/` which is probably not what you wanted. Change it as below

```
RewriteRule ^artist/([^_/]+)$ /artist/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

If that does not fix it completely, let me know the result.

Comment: now i don't get that error anymore but i am redirected to "http://example.com/artist//"

Comment: `example.com/artist//` suggests that the first backereference `$1` is empty. However the rule I gave you `([^_/]+)` should not match an empty string... Can you verify that this rule is identical to the one in your .htaccess.

Comment: i don't know what to say... i changed the code like in my first post like you said... so what should be the problem?

Comment: could that problem was made by the place that the rules ocuppy? i added the last one first (the one that refers to artist-page.php) now it works...